# Input.ChoiceSet inside Action.ShowCard card not working #361

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder to build a bot for Microsoft Teams.
We have the following payload to create a card, which has an Input.ChoiceSet inside an Action.ShowCard card.
It works fine when I preview the card from the bar but it doesn't work after I send the card. Sometimes if I restart the MST client it works when I click on a card for the first time but then it doesn't work after that. Sometimes it never works, only from the preview.

It does work fine on Android but it doesn't work on Linux, Mac or web clients.

Here is a demo of the issue, https://www.loom.com/share/7cfec55b587941899cd66e1d896df065

And here is the payload. Try the Click me! button, which should display a dropdown.

```
{
    "type":"message",
    "attachments":[
        {
            "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content":{
                "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type":"AdaptiveCard",
                "version":"1.2",
                "actions":[
                    {
                        "type":"Action.OpenUrl",
                        "title":"Action 1",
                        "url":"https://my.website.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"Action.Submit",
                        "title":"Action 2",
                        "data":{
                            "command":"action 1",
                            "data":"asdasd"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"Action.ShowCard",
                        "title":"Click me!",
                        "card":{
                            "type":"AdaptiveCard",
                            "version":"1.0",
                            "body":[
                                {
                                    "type":"Input.ChoiceSet",
                                    "id":"SelectUser",
                                    "style":"compact",
                                    "value":"1",
                                    "choices":[
                                        {
                                            "title":"User 1",
                                            "value":"1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "title":"User 2",
                                            "value":"2"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "title":"User 3",
                                            "value":"3"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "height":"stretch",
                                    "wrap":true,
                                    "isMultiSelect":false
                                }
                            ],
                            "actions":[
                                {
                                    "type":"Action.Submit",
                                    "title":"Action 3.1",
                                    "data":{
                                        "command":"action 3.1",
                                        "data":"asdasd"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"Action.ShowCard",
                        "title":"Action 4",
                        "card":{
                            "type":"AdaptiveCard",
                            "body":[
                                {
                                    "type":"Input.Text",
                                    "label":"Enter comment",
                                    "style":"text",
                                    "id":"text",
                                    "isMultiline":true,
                                    "placeholder":"Enter your comment"
                                }
                            ],
                            "actions":[
                                {
                                    "type":"Action.Submit",
                                    "title":"Save",
                                    "data":{
                                        "command":"save",
                                        "data":"asdasd"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "body":[
                    {
                        "type":"TextBlock",
                        "size":"medium",
                        "weight":"bolder",
                        "text":"text... text... text",
                        "wrap":true
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"ColumnSet",
                        "columns":[
                            {
                                "type":"Column",
                                "width":"auto",
                                "items":[
                                    {
                                        "type":"Image",
                                        "style":"Person",
                                        "url":"https://avatar.com/avatar.png",
                                        "size":"small"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type":"Column",
                                "width":"stretch",
                                "items":[
                                    {
                                        "type":"TextBlock",
                                        "weight":"lighter",
                                        "text":"text... text... text",
                                        "wrap":true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type":"TextBlock",
                                        "spacing":"None",
                                        "text":"text... text... text",
                                        "isSubtle":true,
                                        "wrap":true
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"Container",
                        "items":[
                            {
                                "columns":[
                                    {
                                        "spacing":"small",
                                        "width":"auto",
                                        "verticalContentAlignment":"Center",
                                        "type":"Column",
                                        "selectAction":{
                                            "targetElements":[
                                                "fields-content",
                                                "showFields",
                                                "hideFields"
                                            ],
                                            "type":"Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                            "title":"expand"
                                        },
                                        "items":[
                                            {
                                                "type":"TextBlock",
                                                "id":"showFields",
                                                "horizontalAlignment":"Left",
                                                "color":"Accent",
                                                "text":"Show fields",
                                                "wrap":true
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type":"TextBlock",
                                                "id":"hideFields",
                                                "horizontalAlignment":"Left",
                                                "color":"Accent",
                                                "text":"Hide fields",
                                                "wrap":true,
                                                "isVisible":false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type":"ColumnSet"
                            },
                            {
                                "id":"fields-content",
                                "isVisible":false,
                                "type":"Container",
                                "items":[
                                    {
                                        "type":"FactSet",
                                        "facts":[
                                            {
                                                "title":"title",
                                                "value":"value"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo, 
Could you please try with this [adaptive card bot builder](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards) sample.

Comment: Thanks @Rama-MSFT but are those .net samples? I'm using the node library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder
Also if I try my sample using App Studio in Microsoft Teams it works fine, I can see the card with the dropdown. So it seems like the problem is somewhere the node library.

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo,
Currently we don't have the sample code in nodejs.Agree with you problem in using node library. I too tested with your payload.

Comment: Thanks @Rama-MSFT. My workaround for now is to use style: "expanded"

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have the sample code in nodejs.Agree with you problem in using node library. I too tested with your payload.